# Implementation of security policy using BLP

Tags: access-control, permissions, bell-lapadula

I'm studying for an exam that covers BLP (Bell-Lapadula) and I was wondering if the following could be represented using this policy. All the examples I've found online are of a simple hierarchical structure, and aren't much help here. Suppose we have the following scenario (A and B are files, and X,Y,Z are users in the system).

```
File A: Read and writable by X,Y,Z
File B: Read and writable but only by X,Y (Z should have no access).
```

Is something like this possible given the read-down write-up restrictions of BLP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X and Y can read information from File B and write it to File A. This makes formerly confidential information available to Z.

This violates the "no write-down" rule of Bell–LaPadula:

> The Star-property (read "star"-property) - a subject at a given security level must not write to any object at a lower security level (no write-down)